# Does "G-D is not man" mean a man, as in Jesus can't be G-D?

Tags: contradiction

In B'midbar (Numbers) parshat Balak (23:19) we read, "G-D is not a man...."

The same phrase is found in Hoshea 11:9. Cf. 1 Samuel 15.29:
"And also the Glory of Israel will not lie nor repent; for He is not a man, that He should repent.'"

From the context of B'midbar, Hoshea and 1 Sh'muel (Samuel) we find G-D is not man. And from the context of Malachi 3.6 ("I change not therefore you sons of Ya'acov are not consumed."), G-D does not change but is the same forever. Cf. Psalm 102:27 "But You are the same, And Your years will not come to an end.

In light of these passages (passukim - verses), how could G-D become a human being and die a common criminals death as in the case of Jesus?

Comment: Were Christ and Samuel contemporaries ?

Comment: Well inasmuch as 'God is Jesus' is wrong, so is 'God is a man.' The divine nature is not a man. He can take on human nature. You can't define God as 'Jesus' because it distorts the truth. But you can define Jesus as God because He is of that nature, and thus God IN ADDITION to another distinct nature as man, which he assumed as God (Phil 2:). In addition to this, 'God is not a man' even taken in the other sense, would still be true, becaue at the time it was written, God did not yet assume a human nature. His respective natures are capable of the things proper to each: Rev 1:17-18(I was dead)

Comment: Yochanan, if God is one as stated in the Shema, why does Genesis 1:2 make a distinction between God and the Spirit of God? Is this dualism?

Comment: who said B'rashith (Gen.) 1.2 makes such a distinction? There is no duality in HaShem (G-D). G-D does not take on "human nature" as that is a direct contradiction to B'midbar (Numbers) 23.19; (read Maimonides Thirteen Principles of Faith). Man cannot take on G-D's nature either for "G-D is not man" and G-D does not change from limitless Deity to sinful human which is subject to the law of death. (G-D cannot die so therefore Jesus can't be G-D and a crucified human at the same time!)

Answer (score 1):

The answer, which was revealed throughout all the Old Testament(the Hebrew Bible) begins with Gen. 3:15,

> **אֵיבָ֣ה ׀ אָשִׁ֗ית בֵּֽינְךָ֙ וּבֵ֣ין הָֽאִשָּׁ֔ה וּבֵ֥ין זַרְעֲךָ֖
>   וּבֵ֣ין זַרְעָ֑הּ ה֚וּא יְשׁוּפְךָ֣ רֹ֔אשׁ וְאַתָּ֖ה תְּשׁוּפֶ֥נּוּ
>   עָקֵֽב׃ ס**

(And enmity I will put between and between you and the woman, and between her seed and your seed, he shall bruise your head and you shall bruise his heel-Interlinear Translation-I.T.))

God, who gave Adam the Commandment, Gen. 2:17,

> **וּמֵעֵ֗ץ הַדַּ֙עַת֙ טֹ֣וב וָרָ֔ע לֹ֥א תֹאכַ֖ל מִמֶּ֑נּוּ כִּ֗י בְּיֹ֛ום אֲכָלְךָ֥ מִמֶּ֖נּוּ מֹ֥ות תָּמֽוּת׃**

(But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil not eat of for in the day that you eat thereof you shall surely die-I.T.)

did something amazing; instead of striking Adam and Eve dead(physically) at that very moment, gives them a promise: Eve's "seed" would crush the head of the serpent's seed, while the serpent's seed would strike the heel of her seed. It is obvious from the passage that the 'snake' is not being addressed- snakes don't communicate with humans, neither do they have the vocal cords to do so. Furthermore, they crawl on their bellies anyway-being made without arms and legs.

It is apparent that God is speaking to the one "empowering" the snake to speak, and He gives the snake an amazing prophecy: the woman's "seed"(**זַרְעָ֑הּ**-zerah/ singular) will crush the head of the serpent's seed(**זַרְעֲךָ֖**-zeraka/ which can be both singular or plural).

There is another amazing fact: neither the woman, or spirit(Satan) have seed-the seed is in the man. Therefore, instead of killing man instantly, God provides through the woman-not the man, a "seed", which will crush the mortal enemy(Satan) who lied to Eve(and Adam), and caused them to forfeit their lives. The condition is that Satan(the serpent) would have the opportunity to "strike the heel"-the rearmost, unprotected part of man, one that a real snake would have access to. He then gives Adam and Eve skins to cover their nakedness(removing the need for 'fig leaves'(excuses)), and evicts them from the Garden of Eden.

In Isa. 53:10, it says

> **וַיהוָ֞ה חָפֵ֤ץ דַּכְּאֹו֙ הֶֽחֱלִ֔י אִם־תָּשִׂ֤ים אָשָׁם֙ נַפְשֹׁ֔ו
>   :יִרְאֶ֥ה זֶ֖רַע יַאֲרִ֣יךְ יָמִ֑ים וְחֵ֥פֶץ יְהוָ֖ה בְּיָדֹ֥ו יִצְלָֽח**

(the Lord yet it pleased to bruise (him), he has put (him) to grief, when you shall make an offering for sin (of) his soul, he shall see (his) offspring, he shall prolong (his) days, and the pleasure of the Lord in his hand shall prosper.-I.T.)

Satan was allowed to "bruise" the man God conceived in the woman(the virgin) of Isa. 7:14. Because his blood was never touched by the blood of the woman(in the embryonic sac), and he was conceived by God, he was the perfect sacrifice for sin-the payment of his life for the lives of Adam and Eve, and indeed every person brought through the lineage of Adam; who was contaminated by sin.

In Lev. 17:11, it says

> **כִּ֣י נֶ֣פֶשׁ הַבָּשָׂר֮ בַּדָּ֣ם הִוא֒ וַאֲנִ֞י נְתַתִּ֤יו לָכֶם֙
>   עַל־הַמִּזְבֵּ֔חַ לְכַפֵּ֖ר עַל־נַפְשֹׁתֵיכֶ֑ם כִּֽי־הַדָּ֥ם ה֖וּאy
>   בַּנֶּ֥פֶשׁ יְכַפֵּֽר׃**

(For the life of the flesh is in the blood it (is) and I have given to you on the altar to make atonement for your souls for the blood it (is) by reason of the life (that) makes atonement-I.T.)

God prophesied in Gen. 3:15 his "seed"(singular) would make atonement for sin; in the process he would defeat Satan's hold on men. It was prophesied he would be executed with common criminals(Isa. 53:9) in keeping with Satan's striking his heel.

### Conclusion

The woman's seed was conceived by God-making him God. His role, prophesied all through the bible was to make atonement; to do that he had to be the perfect sacrifice(without sin), to take the place of Adam and all mankind-fulfilling God's Commandment against sin.

This is the "sacrifice" God had prepared, who atoned for the sins of many, even as he was "numbered among the transgressors", and yet sits at the right hand of the Father(Ps 110:1).

Answer (score -1):

God is spirit and the father of them. His Holy Spirit,the father and the son. Just as when we look through our own eyes as through a film (dim mirror parable), we are looking with our spirit through the flesh. Jesus was no different except his spirit was the Holy Spirit. Just as I'm a carpenter,truck driver and musician, I never take my music equipment with me on a house site, nor my carpenter tools while driving a truck. I may talk of said tools and make reference to my other jobs, but never do I reveal them all at once while at said job. Only when I'm moving to my new home will I bring all or in the event of making a statement. Jesus in the flesh couldn't enter into heaven because of that flesh. That is until he was given his spiritual body in exchange of the terrestrial body, for flesh and blood cannot walk through walls, disappear into thin air nor abide in the unapproachable light which is probably akin to a nuclear blast. For he is a consuming fire. And as is written. "Do you not think that I cannot be in more than one place at once? "He shall appear in the glory of the father with his holy angels". As can be read in many books, namely Ezekiel, he makes reference to the prince entering in at the east gate,that no man shall enter in that way,that this is for the prince because The Lord entered in that way. In psalms it states,and The Lord said unto my Lord. As written," I will share my glory with no other". He told the Pharisees while being subjected to questions that before Abraham was, I Am". Also," In the beginning was the word and the word was with God,and the word was God and the word became flesh". Prophecies in the old covenant written about the coming messiah stated that he was the messenger of the covenant handed down to Moses.  Different job titles,same being. Makes one view the love and sacrifice that the creator of the universe with all that is in it a little more humbled and with great thanksgiving. Remember how the Angel Gabriel told Mary that for God to do this was a simple thing. Many argue that because Jesus was standing amongst his disciples and God spoke from heaven that they were two different beings. Well as God has made known through his word, that he can indeed be in more than one place at once, just think of it as Jesus making a statement. Like, if you won't believe my voice, then surely you'll believe this one. Him praying to the father was indeed the flesh of earth,or the earthen pot speaking aloud, but bear in mind that he was setting an example as to how we were to pray and how we should make known our faith in him,even in the direst of times.  Another way to think of this is to ask yourself these simple questions. Is the "glory of God separate from God? Is the "word of God" also separate from God? Why certainly not and by no means. So it is with the "Son of God". By the same token and as stated above,since death by sin which is sin in itself and God has no part of sin,the flesh which is the raiment of the spirit is or rather was the reason of his title "The son of Man" and likewise "The Son of God".

Comment: Can you lease [edit] this at least to add paragraph breaks (use blank lines between blocks). Also any blocks that are citations could be separated into block quotes. As it is you have some mistakes in you quotation marks and I can't even make out what you are trying to say for getting lost in them.